# Change value of a column if within a time range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to modify the values of one column if they fall between the following time (17:00 to 23:00), otherwise, they have to keep the same values. This is my code:

```
lclstd['Response KWH/hh (per half hour) ']=lclstd['KWH/hh (per half hour) '].astype(float)
```

Extracting time from datetime column

```
lclstd['Time']=pd.to_datetime(lclstd['DateTime']).dt.strftime ('%H:%M:%S')
```

Assigning response only during peak time from 17:00 to 23:00

```
lclstd.loc[(lclstd['Time'] == '17:00:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '17:30:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '18:00:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '18:30:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '19:00:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '19:30:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '20:00:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '20:30:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '21:00:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '21:30:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '22:00:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '22:30:00') | (lclstd['Time'] == '23:00:00') , 'Response KWH/hh (per half hour) '] = 0.9*lclstd['Response KWH/hh (per half hour) ']
```

but I get the following error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: Could you provide the input dataframe lclstd?

Comment: The data can be download it from this link because it is too heavy, it is one of the 168 files, you can select whatever of those, all of them contain information of 36 different households

https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/smartmeter-energy-use-data-in-london-households

I cut it with the following function to make it easier to manipulate

lclstd=pd.read_csv('Power-Networks-LCL-June2015(withAcornGps)v2_2.csv', index_col=0, nrows=1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) returns [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) objects. So you can perform a comparison via [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) to create mask. Then feed to [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
from datetime import time

time1, time2 = time(17), time(23)                # 17:00, 23:00

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])          # convert to datetime if necessary
mask = df['Time'].dt.time.between(time1, time2)  # inclusive of boundaries by default

df.loc[mask, 'Response KWH/hh (per half hour) '] *= 0.9
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the following error pops up

time() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: Did you `from datetime import time` ? Works fine for me on Python 3.6.

Comment: @JonathanBudez, More likely you've named another variable `time` earlier on (don't do this; use more descriptive variables so there's no clash).